# Print Value of Slider

Tags: javascript, reactjs, slider

I have a slider and want to have it print/display its current value but I can't figure out how to do it.

I know material.ui sliders have the Prop valueLabelDisplay but for my purpose I want the value displayed somewhere else.

```
function valuetext(value) {
    return `${value}`;
  }

  export default function SliderBars() {
    const classes = useStyles();
    const [value, setValue] = React.useState([23, 37]);

    return (
      <div className={classes.root}>
        <Typography id="range-slider1" gutterBottom>
          Option 1
        </Typography>
        <Slider
          //value={value}
          min="0" max ="10" step = "1"
          valueLabelDisplay="auto"
          aria-labelledby="range-slider1"
          getAriaValueText={valuetext}
          defaultValue={5}
          marks
        />
```

Answer (score 0):

If I got you right, you need to use `onChange` event of the Slider, see it here: https://material-ui.com/api/slider/ and do something like this:

```
...
onSliderChange = (val) => {
  setValue(val);
}


...
<div>{value}</div>
<Slider
      //value={value}
      min="0" max ="10" step = "1"
      valueLabelDisplay="auto"
      aria-labelledby="range-slider1"
      getAriaValueText={valuetext}
      defaultValue={5}
      onChange={(event, val) => this.onSliderChange(val)}
      marks
    />
```

Comment: Do I define onSliderChange as its own function, during the export, or somewhere else?

Comment: it should be inside of SliderBars component as a normal named function, because there setValue hook is available and this hook should be used to update the slider value. Let me know whether it works or not